# Region of convergence for the series of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Find out the region of convergence for the following series of function.

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{\log (m)}$$

Here $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This is a series of function. I was trying to find out the radius of convergence by Root Test and Ratio test. But no suitable solution I am getting.

What will be the region of convergence if we consider $x \in \mathbb{C}$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's not a power series.

Comment: I was making a mistake assuming the series as a power series. Here the powers are not integers. It is only a series of function.

Answer (score 1):

$x \in \mathbb{R}$ ??. How do we define $(-2)^{log(2)}$ ? And in my opinion, this is not really a power-series .

 As what I solved, this series converges if and only if $ x \in [0; \frac{1}{e})$

**Hint**: 
Rewrite the series as :

 $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \sum_{m=[e^k]}^{[e^{k+1}]-1} x^{log(m)} $ (where $[.]$ is floor function) 
And we see that:
$( [e^{k+1}]-1-[e^k]).x^{k-1} \le \sum_{m=[e^k]}^{[e^{k+1}]-1} x^{log(m)} \le ( [e^{k+1}]-1-[e^k])x^{k+1}$(*)
Which leads to the interval of convergence.

Comment: Please expand the hint a little.

Comment: As you might see, if we denote $a_k=\sum_{m=[e^k]}^{ [e^{k+1}]-1} x^{logm}$ then $sum=\sum a_k $<br> And if you use the ineq i provided above and ratio test, you'll find the interval of convergence :)

Comment: I misspelled. Root Test, not Ratio Rest :)

Comment: I do not know how to rewrite the sum as $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \sum_{m = [e^k]}^{[e^{k+1}]-1} x^{\log (m)}$. May be it is very easy, please discuss it a little. Is $x^{k - 1} \leq x^{\log(m)} \leq x^{k+1}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $r=|x|$. Since $\log m\to+\infty$, for every definition of the complex power, $|x^{\log m}|=r^{\log m}\to+\infty$ if $r\gt1$, thus the series diverges. If $r\lt1$ then $r^{\log m}\to0$ and $r^{n+1}\leqslant r^{\log m}\leqslant r^n$ for every $n\geqslant0$ and every $m$ such that $n\leqslant\log m\leqslant n+1$. The number of indices $m$ corresponding to a given $n$ is of the order of $\mathrm e^n$ such hence the positive series $\sum\limits_mr^{\log m}$ converges if and only if the series $\sum\limits_n\mathrm e^nr^n$ converges, that is, when $r\lt1/\mathrm e$.

Thus, the series $\sum\limits_mx^{\log m}$ diverges when $|x|\geqslant1$ and converges absolutely when $|x|\lt1/\mathrm e$. It diverges when $x$ is a positive real and $x\geqslant1/\mathrm e$. It remains to see whether the series $\sum\limits_mr^{\log m}\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta\log m}$ converges (simply) when $1/\mathrm e\leqslant r\lt1$ and $0\lt\theta\lt2\pi$.

Comment: I do not understand the last sentence of the first paragraph. Please...

Comment: Please describe what it is that you fail to understand in it.

Comment: How we are saying "There are $\Theta(e^n)$ such indices $m$"? What is $\Theta$? How $\sum_m r^m$ converges iff $\sum_n e^n r^n$ convergence.

Comment: See edited version.

Answer (score -1):

One idea would be to use the fact that $\:x^{\log(m)}=e^{\log(m)\log(x)}=e^{\log(m)\Large(\normalsize\log(x)/\log(m)\Large)}\underset{m\to\infty}{\sim}e^{\log(m)}.$